# Variables declared inside a loop

Tags: c, for-loop

If I were to declare a variable inside of a loop, is it faster to have the declaration outside of the loop? Does the program reallocate the memory for `n` at each iteration or use the same memory location throughout?

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    int n = getNumber();
    printf("%d\n",n);
}
```

versus

```
int n;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    n = getNumber();
    printf("%d\n",n);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Variables are not really "created" or "destroyed". They are concepts at the abstraction level of the programming language. The compiler is not required to have a one to one mapping between a variable and memory addresses. In practice, most of the time, stack space for local variables is allocated at once at the beginning of the function, so it won't make a difference in performance.

Note that, C++, unlike C, which doesn't have a notion for constructors, supports object construction and destruction, so if you were to define a variable of a class type in a for loop, like the following,

```
class MyClass { 
    public: MyClass() { cout << "hello world" << endl; }
};
//...
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
   MyClass m;
}
```

you'd call its constructor every time, effectively printing "hello world" ten times. This is very different from C declarations and should not be confused with it.

Comment: Thanks, I meant is the memory reallocated at each iteration. I've changed the question.

Answer (score 14):

Any modern compiler would optimise these to the same machine code, so you should see no difference.

Comment: Defining in the loop is clearer and might produce more optimised code since the compiler knows the lifetime (although probably not for a simple type)

Answer (score 1):

For most modern compilers, this doesn't matter. They will assign processor registers or place the variables on the stack as efficiently as possible.