# What happens if an array is declared of different sizes at each iteration in a loop?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, optimization, memory

See the following program
I think it is different from declaring variables inside loop, because they occupy constant space, so once they are allocated it will be enough, but in case of array, size of array is variable(in the below program, intentionally size is kept small) what if next size of redeclared array is large, or due to size some issue, will it redeclare array at some other location?.By playing with it, i observed that every redeclared array was constructed by extending same memory of previously declared array.Is there any possibility that it can't be extended for newly declared array?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n = 5; 
    while(5){
        int a[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n ; ++i){
            a[i] = 0;
        }
        f[n--] = a;  
        if(n == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
```

So here Array a[n] is being declared multiple times of different sizes,

- What happens to previous declaration?

Please explain what is happening in this program, why is it printing zero as content?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int* f[10]; 
int main(void) { 
    int n = 5; 
    while(5){ 
        int a[n]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < n ; ++i){ 
            a[i] = 5; 
        } 
        f[n--] = a; 
        if(n == 0) break; 
    } 
    printf("\ndone\n"); 

    while(++n < 5){ 
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){ 
            printf("\nat size = %-3d : base address = %-7d : a[%d] = %-4d at" 
                   "address = %-7d ", n , f[n],i, *(f[n]+i), (f[n]+i)); 
        } 
        printf("\n\n"); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variables declared inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735765/variables-declared-inside-a-loop)

Comment: You don't have to worry about freeing local and static variables. It's dynamically allocated memory (malloc, calloc, strdup, etc) you need to free.

Comment: @GalAbra This question has a difference to the provided duplicate. The array in this case has different sizes between the iterations. While the `int` object in the duplicate has fixed size. This requires a quite different answer. Don´t vote to close as duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, the variable declared inside a scope (loop, if/else, function, switch) are destroyed/created when reaching the end of a scope or starting.

In practice, the code generated by the compiler will cause the function reuse the same memory area for the loop variable. So you could see remains from previous loop iterations, but you shouldn't rely on those, it is just that memory does not get wiped.

So, when a variable is declared inside a scope (`{ }`), consider it to be a new variable when reaching the start of the scope (i.e. it needs to be assigned a value inside the scope before being read). But trust the compiler to optimize the "creation/destruction" of the variable, as it will just reuse memory of variables from other scopes/iterations that are no longer accessible.

Comment: sir i added one more program in my question please go through it ,would you explain why i can  access those arrays which are no longer in scope and why do they initialized to  zero?(or might be thinking completely wrong)