# For a local variable declared in a loop is memory allocated each iteration?

Tags: java

I was surprised to read in Cay Horstmann's Java 9 book, that memory is allocated each time to the temporary, in an enhanced for loop:

> "a new variable arg is created in each iteration" (Chap 3, page 126)

```
for(String arg:args) {
...
}
```

I always thought the compiler would allocate the space for a local variable in a loop, before entering the loop, to optimize performance.

Why would the variable be created each time?

This question was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735765/variables-declared-inside-a-loop) in the context of C, but not for Java. I am asking for a loop in general, not just this case.

Comment: A new variable (reference in Java) gets created every time, as it points to a different value  in each iteration. But memory - may be/ maybe not - read about string literal pool?

Comment: @Kris: this has nothing to do with the string pool at all. Any strings referenced by `arg` will already have existed in `args`, so no new string object will be created anyway.

Comment: @JoachimSauer You are right, the question title contained memory allocation, so I mentioned.

Comment: Memory for local variables is not "allocated" in the classical way, instead the JVM will just reserve enough memory for all local variables of a given method (which is known at compile time). While `arg` can be treated as a new variable (with a new value) in each iteration, it will almost certainly re-use the same slot (i.e. the same position in memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (String s : ...) { }
double x;
for (int i : ...) {
   long n; ...
}
double y;
```

For the above the compiler will declare 5 variable slots on the call stack, which can be overlapping (x sharing the memory with s). The needed stack size is added to the method, so stackoverflow can be checked.

Only any assignment, like object creation, is repeated inside the loop.

However that is as needed. A beginner's error is:

```
List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
A obj = new A(); // *** ERROR ***
for (...) {
    obj.name = ...;
    list.add(obj);
}
```

Filling the list with the same object instance whose fields are of the last loop step.

A repeated creation of say `n` is not done. It is certainely no optimisation to place the declaration outside the for-loop on a call - on the contrary: the variable slot on the stack remains after the loop.

Comment: "Certainly is absolute no optimisation to place the declaration outside the for-loop on a call - on the contrary.". please clarify - this sentence is not coherent to me.

Comment: Outside the compiler must allocate a slot for the variable n. Inside the loop the slot can be reclaimed when the scope of the loop finishes. The stack address of y can be immediately after x. Saving stack space.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer? Please edit this sentence "Certainly is absolute no optimisation to place the declaration outside the for-loop on a call - on the contrary."

Comment: @likejudo it was indeed not clean English or even very coherent. Thanks for the opportunity to correct it as yet.